# Is Remote attribute validation considered as server side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to check if a username is already taken on my database, so i used a remote attribute, is this considered as server side validation, or client side validation.

if it is client side, do i need to do a second check for this on the server, and how to do it, because i used to work only with ready as.net MVC attributes for server side validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would still be considered as client side validation. The remote attribute uses the jquery validation plugin.

You would still need to do a second check for this on the server as if the user had javascript disabled then this validation would not take place.

Just make sure that as part of your user creation process that you check if the username is already taken before you create the user.